# Should a question be downvoted if the OP flags to delete after realising their mistake?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, down-votes, etiquette

I asked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169307/number-of-questions-doesnt-match) question today and after seeing the answer, realised that I had made a mistake in asking the question. I quickly put up a comment that I had flagged the question to be deleted and realised my mistake. I still got downvoted on the question.

So, what is the etiquette on downvoting a question when the OP has already flagged the question to be deleted, realised their mistake and put up a comment to apologise?

Comment: The simple answer is that users are free to vote however they see fit. There's really no etiquette to put on this. I find the particular downvote pointless. But that's just me.

Comment: Downvote got nothing to do with flags. Someone saw a question with obvious mistake and downvoted, it's totally valid. Just take it as a lesson and think twice before reporting a bug, check your details, look for existing reports etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downvoting is totally up to the community. It is the way they express their opinion. You can't force people to have a specific opinion.